# Preseed config (using cubic) is ignored during installation

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, encryption, preseed

I want to create ubuntu (desktop version) iso, which contains preinstalled apps and install with full disc encryption with LVM. The first part was successfully solved using Cubic, but the "forced" encryption (omit questions during installation) does not works well.

Cubic allows us to create preseed files, and puts it into iso (.../preseed/enc.seed) - but when I try to install ubuntu with that iso, then all the questions still appear. What do I wrong? Below my enc.seed file:

```
ubiquity partman-auto/method string crypto
ubiquity partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
ubiquity partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
ubiquity partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
ubiquity partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string crypt
ubiquity partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
ubiquity partman-auto/choose_recipe select root-encrypted
ubiquity partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      root-encrypted ::                                       \
              500 500 500 ext3                                \
                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
              .                                               \
              2000 2000 2000 linux-swap                       \
                      $lvmok{ } lv_name{ swap }               \
                      in_vg { crypt }                         \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
              .                                               \
              500 10000 1000000000 ext4                       \
                      $lvmok{ } lv_name{ root }               \
                      in_vg { crypt }                         \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                                               \
              2000 2000 2000 ext4                             \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ keep }                          \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      label{ rescuedisk }                     \
              .

ubiquity partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
ubiquity partman-basicfilesystems/no_mount_point boolean false
ubiquity partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
ubiquity partman/choose_partition select finish
ubiquity partman/confirm boolean true
ubiquity partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

Btw. When I try to add `ubiquity localechooser/supported-locales string en_US.UTF-8` or any other "chooser" option - still I have to choose it during installation. Maybe this could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so one thing I forget is that preseed files are not automatically loaded. We can simply activate it via **/isolinux/txt.cfg** file (in cubic you can configure it on the last tab called **ISO Boot Configurations**.

My txt.cfg:

```
default live
label live
    menu label ^Install Ubuntu
    kernel /casper/vmlinuz
    append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ks.seed auto=true priority=critical automatic-ubiquity keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=pl boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd quiet splash ---
```

You have also had to create a new preseed file **preseed/ks.seed**. You can do it manually, or using cubic on **Preseed Files** tab, click **"+"** button and call it ks.seed. You can change the name, but you have to change it in txt.cfg too.

I will paste my seed file below (lvm, encryption). It is possible that it is not super-well written preseed, but do the work.

```
d-i partman-auto/method string crypto
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string crypt
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase password 1234
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase-again password 1234
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select root-encrypted
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      root-encrypted ::                                       \
              500 500 500 ext3                                \
                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
              .                                               \
              8000 8000 8000 linux-swap                       \
                      $lvmok{ } lv_name{ swap }               \
                      in_vg { crypt }                         \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
              .                                               \
              500 10000 1000000000 ext4                       \
                      $lvmok{ } lv_name{ root }               \
                      in_vg { crypt }                         \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .

d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/no_mount_point boolean false
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true


# Enable extras.ubuntu.com.
d-i    apt-setup/extras    boolean true
# Install the Ubuntu desktop.
tasksel    tasksel/first    multiselect ubuntu-desktop
# On live DVDs, don't spend huge amounts of time removing substantial
# application packages pulled in by language packs. Given that we clearly
# have the space to include them on the DVD, they're useful and we might as
# well keep them installed.
ubiquity    ubiquity/keep-installed    string icedtea6-plugin openoffice.org
d-i  base-installer/kernel/altmeta   string hwe-18.04
```

I hope that will help someone.

Comment: Also wanted to comment that in newer Ubuntu installs (e.g. 20.04+), the `.seed` files are no longer used but adding `user-data` and `meta-data` to the Preseed Files appears to work, with some additional tweaking of the Grub config.